# Get the parameterized type of a generic in class definition

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a class that takes in a parameterized type, which I am trying to parameterize.

So I have a User object which has an ID. I am making ID a parameterized type. I have a class called `Router` that needs to provide one method `T route(List<T>);`, where `T extends User`.

Within `Router` I have some utility methods where I need to group by an ID within User, which is also parameterized. So `User` looks like `User<K>`, where `K` is the type of ID. So I would have a method that looks like the following within Router:

```
public T route(List<T> listToRoute) {
  Map<K, Double> someUtilityMap = groupValueById(listToRoute);
  // apply some logic
  return chooseFinalCandidate(someUtilityMap);
}
```

Currently I have:

```
public class Router<K, T extends User<K>> {
```

Is there a cleaner way to get and reference `K` within `Router` without the callers having to provide it explicitly in instantiation? Can I somehow just give `T` and then use `K` in the `Router` implementation?

I need to reference `K` explicitly in code, so something like:

```
Map<K, Double> groupValueById(List<T> routingCandidates) {
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
new Router<User<Integer>>();
```

as opposed to:

```
new Router<Integer, User<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Do you also need to have a name for type T in class Router? Otherwise it will be possible to make it just ```class Router<K>```. Did you try this?

Comment: I do need access to both, yes.

Comment: Show more of your code, please. I would like to see if there is another way.

Comment: The main method would be something like:
  `T route(List<T> users)`

which needs to do things like grouping of these users in order to make a routing decision. 

`private Map<K, Double> groupValueById(List<T> users) {`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the signature or your class to `public class Router2<K>`.

Currently, I understand, you have something like

```
public class Router<K, T extends User<K>> {
  Map<K, Double> groupValueById(List<T> routingCandidates) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then call it like

```
List<User<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Router<Integer, User<Integer>> router = new Router<>();
Map<Integer, Double> map = router.groupValueById(list);
```

You can change it to something like

```
public class Router<K> {
  <T extends User<K>> Map<K, Double> groupValueById(List<T> routingCandidates) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and call it like

```
List<User<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Router<Integer> router = new Router<>();
Map<Integer, Double> map = router.groupValueById(list);
```

Although it might seem that we only move the problem to another place, it makes it much simpler to use the class, because you do not need to write down the generic type parameters when using the method.

I think there are two concepts here, that have to be kept separated:

1. The type parameter of the class
2. The type that the class operates on

The only varibale type that is not known in advance and that has to be filled in is `K`. When you know `K`, you can derive `User<K>` from it. `User` is always the same. So this class should have only one type parameter: `K`. This is sufficient for defining the concrete classes.

The class operates on objects of type `User<K>`. You try to express this by type parameters, but this is not what generics are made for. I do not know of a way to capture the `K` from `User<K>` and I think it is not necessary here. It would only make the definition more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I need. Only because semantically speaking, I need a `Router` that handles `User` objects. Not a `Router` that knows about `Integer` or whatever the actual ID value is. The typing of the key within `User` is for utility methods within `Router`, not the interface-fulfilling implementation. I've updated the question a bit more to reflect this.

Comment: @Anthony, look at my new edit, please. I still think, ```User ``` should not appear at all in the type parameters of the class.